# Elementary bound on operator norm on symmetric tensors: reference request

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, operator-norms

My education didn't really cover Tensors very well, so I'm getting stumped by a quite elementary question.

Let $T_k$ be a type k symmetric tensor. We can define the "operator norm" (or the induced norm from the $L_2$ norm on vectors) as:

$$||T_k|| = \max_{a_1,\dots,a_k} \frac{|T(a_1,\dots,a_k)|}{\prod||a_i||_2} $$

This norm answers the question of how big the result can be when we put norm 1 vectors inside the Tensor. I like this definition because, when you use it, it's obvious that if you define a type (k-1) tensor by fixing one input of $T_k$, then the norm of that guy is bounded by the products of the norm of $T_k$ and the vector

But we could use a slightly different definition (and it's the one I was taught a long time ago), where you define the norm as the max when all inputs are the same:

$$ ||T_k|| = \max_{a} \frac{|T(a,a,\dots,a)|}{||a||_{2}^k}  $$

Unless I made a huge mistake, these two definitions are actually equivalent. I've got a smallish proof by induction but it's quite ugly too, and I'm sure this is a basic result of linear-algebra.

Could anybody please point me to a good reference on the subject ? Thank you for your time

Comment: The fact that the two norms are equivalent follows from the polarisation identity which tells you that a symmetric form is characterised uniquely by its value on the diagonal.  e.g., for $k=2$, you have that $$T_2(a,b) = \frac12 (T_2(a+b,a+b)-T_2(a,a)-T_2(b,b))$$.

Comment: Is that really enough ? I wish to prove: $$ ||T_k|| = \max_{a_1,\dots,a_k} \frac{|T(a_1,\dots,a_k)|}{\prod||a_i||_2} = \max_{a} \frac{|T(a,a,\dots,a|}{||a||_2^k} $$ From your equality, I see how to prove a 3/2 upper bound, but not how to go further

Comment: Equivalence of norms is weaker than strict equality.  I thought that this was what you were after.

Comment: Just stumbled on this old question. This is actually due to Banach. See this paper and references: https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/bdl033

Answer (score 1):

I think this is theorem 2.1 in the paper:

THE BEST RANK-1 APPROXIMATION OF A SYMMETRIC
TENSOR AND RELATED SPHERICAL OPTIMIZATION PROBLEMS, by
XINZHEN ZHANG, CHEN LING, AND LIQUN QI.